# np.column_stack() use within loop

Tags: python-2.7

I am wondering if there is a way to make this code work. Hopefully it's clear what I want to do.

I was hoping that after each iteration, a new row would be created within the array. Instead, it seems like the previous row is overwritten - unsurprisingly.

Is there another way to do this?

```
list1 = [4, 5]   

for j in list1:

           one = j + 1
           two = j + 2
           array = np.column_stack( (one, two) )

print(array)

#Output
[[ 6 7]]

#What I actually want
[[ 5 6]
 [ 6 7]]
```

Answer (score -1):

The natural way to do this in Python would be:

```
import numpy

list1 = [4,5]
array = numpy.column_stack((j+1,j+2) for j in list1)

print(array)
```

Some people refer to this way of coding as [pythonic](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/) while your approach is more similar to what one would do in C++ or Java. You'll get used to that if you continue working with Python.

Consulting the documentation of [numpy.colum_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html), you'll see that the function argument is a tuple of columns that will be 'stacked' into a 2d array.
This tuple can be generated as

```
[(j+1,j+2) for j in list1]
```

(which is also a valid line of Python code). Used inside a function argument, we can omit the square braces.

Your example doesn't work because you overwrite *array* in every single loop iteration. I recommend using a debugger ... or adding a print(array) inside the for loop to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't appear to work in my code though

Comment: To be sure, I just tested the code in both python2.7 and python3.5 and it's working as expected. I've extended the explanation and pointed out why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Hey thanks!  It works, but not really for the purposes of my code. The code above is a small example of my code. My for loop is much larger and contains many things. I was hoping that there would be a way similar to the way I suggested.

Comment: I'd rather split up the loop ... but if you insist: you can create an empty list: array = [] before your loop and call array.append([3,4,5]) in each iteration. (A list is better suited for dynamic growth.) and convert it into an numpy.array afterwards.

Comment: Another option is to create a numpy array of fixed size before your loop, e.g., a = numpy.zeros((2,2)), and fill in the columns in each step: a[:,0] = [1,2]